# Iterator over pointer to pointer structure

Tags: c++, stl, const-iterator

I have written a custom container over two structures: an array of T `T* _a` and an array of pointers to T `T** _b`.
The first array is a simple one, the second array contains pointers to the cells of the first one.

The iterators for both structures are const and random access ones. I have implemented all the methods, and the iterator for the first structure works fine. For the second one... not so much.
Compiling, I get this error when I try to iterate over the elements with `begin()` and `end()`:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘int**’ to ‘const int**’ [-fpermissive]
         return const_iterator(_b);
```

But I cannot figure out how to solve it. I understand that it's because the constructor asks for a pointer to a pointer to a constant

```
const_iterator(const T **p) : ptr(p) {}
```

But that's not what I have, as `_b` is an attribute of the container and it's not constant. For the other iterator it works just fine (the only thing changing are a couple of more dereferences in the iterator class).

[Here's](https://pastebin.com/YPcnhtCe) the code of the problematic iterator. [Here's](https://pastebin.com/wXE3iekz) the one that works. What should there be other differences other than the one I made? Thanks!

Comment: `T const **` != `T *const*` != `T **const`.

Comment: Pointer declarations are supposed to be read according to spiral rule, which is "simplified" to right-to-left reading order in this case. So `const T **p` is not a constant pointer, it is a non-constant pointer to non-const pointer to constant T.

Comment: I understand that the argument of `const_iterator` is a pointer to a pointer to a constant T. For my other (working) iterator I have `other_const_iterator(const T *p) : ptr(p) {}`, which works, and would have a non-constant pointer to a constant T. So it seems logic to me having a non-constant pointer to a non-constant pointer to a constant T in `const_iterator`, but it doesn't seem to be. Maybe the issue isn't there, but the error just chokes up in that point. but I still don't understand.

Comment: `int*` can be implicitly converted to `const int*`, but `int**` cannot be implicitly converted to `const int**`: if such a conversion were allowed, it would allow one to modify a const variable without any explicit casts, thus violating const correctness. Make `ptr` have type `const T* const*` or `T* const*` (either should work; you decide whether your design calls for deep or shallow `const` propagation).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the issue, I didn't understand well const decay and how to read declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as Igor said in the comments about int** conversion to const int**. I thought it worked like int* but it doesn't. I found more info [here](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html).